# Loop through list and compare against nested dict. avoiding KeyError - Python

Tags: python

I would like to do the following:

I got to the following code so far, but I'm stuck now how to ignore that Day from future actions performed in the loop.

If someone could help me that would be really appreciated!!

- Note that I cannot remove EU as a region, it needs to be taken into the logic even though the key is not in the nested dict.

Comment: Please add complete code, that we could debug it and see more. In C# you cannot remove elements from lists/dictionaries that you currently loop through it. Is that also a problem in Python?

Answer (score 0):

error has to do with your

```
print("{} status is: ".format(region) + nested_status)
```

nested_status is NullType, but the print statement is expecting a string.

You could try something like this to avoid 'NonTypes'

```
dict.get(key[, default])
example
dict.get(key, -1)
```

check this snippet and modify your code accordingly

```
print(nested)
nested['SA'].pop('20200525')
print(nested)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for you answer, I get a syntax error when I add that to the code.. Also do you maybe know how I can work with 'day' but without 20200704 after it has been identified as 'C'? As I need it for a query with Day in an append: VALUE = {day}"

Comment: Despite the way this is written, you shouldn't use the square brackets.  They are just there to show that the field is optional.  In practice you would use this like `myValue = myDictionary.get(key, defaultValue)`

Comment: Turksarama - thanks!  I updated code with an example

Comment: Thanks for getting the error! it gives now that the value is: C.. Now that I know that.. How can I Ignore that day further in the loop?

Comment: i modified the code. use the pop method on your nested dict to consume it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, check the updated answer at the bottom.

The reason you getting the "can not concatenate" Error is because "nested_status" is equal to "None" in some iterations and you tried to add a string to it ('...' + None) in the print statement.
you should check if nested_status has a value first.

```
import datetime

dates = [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(
    2020, 7, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 7, 0, 0)]

regions = ["SA", "CA", "EU"]

nested = {"SA": {"20200525": "H", "20201126": "C", "20201224": "H", "20200101": "C", "20201127": "C", "20200217": "C", "20200120": "C", "20200907": "C", "20200410": "C", "20200704": "C",
                 "20201225": "C"}, "CA": {"20200410": "C", "20200518": "C", "20200701": "C", "20200101": "C", "20201012": "C", "20201228": "C", "20201225": "C", "20200803": "C", "20200907": "C", "20200217": "C"}}

for region in regions:
    for d in dates:
        day = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")

        if (nested.get(region) or {}).get(day):
            print("Nested value found in {} ! {}".format(region, day))
        nested_status = (nested.get(region) or {}).get(day)
        if nested_status:
            if nested_status == 'C':
                continue                 #<-- skip this loop iteration if C
            print("{} status is: ".format(region) + nested_status)
```

if you are not interested "if nested_status == C" just skip the current date iteration.

```
if nested_status:
    if nested_status == 'C':
        continue                 #<-- skip this loop iteration if C
    print("{} status is: ".format(region) + nested_status)
```

Comment: Why do we still need the print statement at the end? Does is belong to if nested_status: ??

Comment: I put it at the end because I assumed that you only want to print it if it's value is other than "C" but if you want to print it even if is value is "C", you can place it before the "if nested_status == 'C'" statement.

Comment: Ok thanks! probably I will delete it since it was more for debugging purposed now.. But thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated my last comment you can include the print statement but it's value is going to be "C" which I assume you don't care for that.

Comment: Just remember whenever a "continue" statement is added inside a loop like a for loop or a while loop, that iteration is going to be skipped and any code that belongs to that loop that is below  "continue"  will be skipped